# Xcode 5 for Snow Leopard

Tags: xcode5

Can I get xcode 5 for snow leopard when I register as an apple developer or is my software too dated? I have not registered as a developer yet so not sure if I can.

Thanks

Comment: The latest version of OS X, Mavericks, is free - http://www.apple.com/uk/osx/

Comment: Being registered or not makes no difference. You have the same access to Xcode regardless. Registering only adds the ability to install an app on a real device and submit to Apple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need at least OS X 10.8.4 to run XCode 5: [What's New in XCode 5](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012953-SW18).